# how to include dependencies as jars in maven

Tags: java, maven, executable-jar

I have a jar building task like this:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <manifestEntries>
                                    <Main-Class>com.example.App</Main-Class>
                                </manifestEntries>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

when I export the jar from eclipse as a runable jar the dependencies stay as JAR files inside the output jar, like this:

[image: dependencies as jars]

but when I build it like so, maven decompress and merge all sources into the same jar:

[image: dependencies decompressed]

how can I indicate in the maven task to make it include the jars without being decompressed?

Comment: Using the maven-shade-plugin is exactly intended to create a so called executable jar which contains all needed things which in consequence means they have to be decompressed and put into the single jar.otherwise you can't run them via `java -jar ...`. Having jars inside a jar will not work...the quesiton is why do you like to go that way?

Comment: @khmarbaise it does work as I'm showing in the image, different jars have resources that are being overwritten and make the jar throw errors when I try to make it run

Comment: The maven-shade-plugin does not has a configuration with `<descriptorRefs>..</descriptorRefs>`...that can be removed...

Comment: @khmarbaise is there anther plugin that put the dependencies in jar form in a separated folder?

Comment: You can use the maven-assembly-plugin for that purpose...but the question is is this the right way to go? What kind of application are you developing?